# c# Linq method is not following one of my conditions that I set

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, c#-6.0

I'm trying to create a list like you see below.

For some reason, it follows the first two conditions, isPublished and IsRPG == false.  But it ignores the ShelfDate.

I want all games where the ShelfDate is greater than or equal to the current date.

But it will show games that have any ShelfDate...

BTW ShelfDate is of type DateTime.

Here is my code:

```
var games = await _context.Game
   .Where(x => x.IsPublished == isPublished && x.IsRPG == false && x.ShelfDate >= DateTime.Now)
   .Select(x => new GameEntity
   { ... }
```

Here are the models for Game and GameEntity:

```
public partial class Game
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShelfDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime IsPublished { get; set; }
    public bool IsRPG { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}   


public partial class GameEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShelfDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime IsPublished { get; set; }
    public bool IsRPG { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

I am getting no errors.

Thanks!

Comment: `=>` should be `<=` or `>=`

Comment: @juunas oops sorry, that was a typo when I was typing out my code.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the model class that you are using + any configurations for its column types etc?

Comment: (=>) is a lambda expression and (>=) is the greater than equal to sign

Comment: @juunas thanks, I added the models being used.

Comment: Maybe `DateTime.Now` is not recognized by your data provider, and needs to be set earlier and not be evaluated by the query ?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` produces a date time in the local time zone. Does the database store the dates as UTC or some other time zone? `DateTime.UtcNow` will create a time in UTC timezone.

Comment: @JeremyF. That was it!  I set a local DateTime variable to DateTime.Now.Date before running the Linq query.  It works! Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell have you tried `x.ShelfDate >= DateTime.Now.Date` instead of `x.ShelfDate >= DateTime.Now`in your query?

Comment: Why do you use `x.IsRPG == false`, if you can do `!x.IsRPG`? Do you really need `==` there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Putting the response here.*

`DateTime.Now` is not recognized by your data provider, and needs to be set earlier and not be evaluated by the query, assuming you're using Entity Framework.